# Trying to use this.props.history.push but this.props returns an empty object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
var React = require('react')
var axios = require('axios')
var config = require('../../apiKeys')
var ReactRouter = require('react-router-dom')
var Router = ReactRouter.BrowserRouter;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var Forecast = require('./Forecast');

class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      city: null,
      weatherData: []
    };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  };
  handleChange(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let input = e.target.value.split(' ,')[0];
    this.setState(function() {
      return {
        city: input
      }
    });
  };

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    city = this.state.city

    function getCurrentWeather(city) {
      return axios.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+ city + `&type=accurate&APPID=${config.apiKey}`)
        .then(function(response) {
          return(response.data)
        })
      };

    function getFiveDayForecast(city) {
      return axios.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=" + city + `,us&mode=XML&APPID=${config.apiKey}&cnt=5`)
        .then(function(response) {
          return(response.data)
        })
      };
    axios.all([getCurrentWeather(city), getFiveDayForecast(city)])
      .then(axios.spread((currentWeatherResponse, fiveDayResponse) => {
        this.setState({ weatherData: [...this.state.weatherData, currentWeatherResponse] })
        this.setState({ weatherData: [...this.state.weatherData, fiveDayResponse]})
      }))
      .then(() => {
        this.props.history.push({
          pathname: '/forecast',
          search: `?forecast?city=${this.state.city}`,
          state: {
              data: this.state.weatherData}
        })
      });
    };

  render() {

    console.log(this.props.children)
    return(
      <Router>
        <div className="header-style">
          <p className="header-content-style"> Weather React App! </p>
          <div className="search-header">
            <form className="header-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <input
                className="header-input-form"
                id="location"
                placeholder="City & State"
                type="text"
                autoComplete="off"
                onChange={this.handleChange}/>
              <button
                className="header-bar-button"
                type="submit"
                >
                Get Weather
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}


module.exports = Header



var React = require('react')
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom')
require('./index.css')
var Home = require('./component/Home')
var ReactRouter = require('react-router-dom')
var Router = ReactRouter.BrowserRouter;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var Link = ReactRouter.Link
var Forecast = require('./component/Forecast')
var Interval = require('./component/Interval')

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Route exact path="/" component = {Home} />
          <Route path="/forecast" component={Forecast} />
          <Route path="/detail/:interval" component = {Interval} />
        </div>
      </ Router>
    )
  }
};


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

I have a header component that has a form for searching by city & state. The form onSubmit triggers an event function that has a couple of function declarations for api calls and one function evocation that wraps to the api calls in an axios.all. The response is then set to my this.state, and then has a this.props.history.push function to render the new component and route. Upon console.log, my this.props is an empty object and I cant call .history.push on undefined.

Im trying to figure out why this.props is empty in this particular component when I've done something somewhat similar in another component that actually has this.props.history. The top code is from my Header Component, the bottom is my index.js file

Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

To get `history` in your `props` you need you [component wrapped](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md) up `withRouter`

```
module.exports = withRouter(Header);
```

`withRouter` takes responsibility to find Router and pass all related props to your component.

Comment: Thank you! Just implemented this not too long ago and I got it figured out!